# Como usar requireFailure no Hammer.js?

Tags: javascript, hammerjs

Não sei exatamente como definir o elemento em que aplicar a minha função no frame Hammer.js. Lá na API do próprio é passada a seguinte sintaxe:

```
var horizontal = new Hammer.Pan({
    event: 'panh',
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
});
var vertical = new Hammer.Pan({
    event: 'panv',
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL
});
vertical.requireFailure(horizontal);
```

Não imagino uma forma de aplicar esse código ao meu projeto. Gostaria de ter os efeitos no elemento `document.getElementById('hitArea')`, se isso puder ser útil.

Comment: Qual é o link para essa página da API do Hammer.js?

Comment: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/ ou http://hammerjs.github.io/api/